# Manage deployment versions with TFS without devops procedure

Tags: tfs, agile, versions

We are using the TFS for managing our tasks/bugs in Agile methodology.

Currently we don't have DevOps to handle CI/CD procedures, we just manually upload the publish to our private server after our QA made his tests and approved the release branch.

My question is, since in agile development i can deploy to production every time my  project manager asks me to (since the feature he asked for is ready and made it with the tests), how can i use the TFS to "grab" all those tasks/features/bugs that went to production and show her what is new on production?

My first choice was to use the Tags to tag items as "1.1.2". But then i thought that someone will still need to mark it at some point as "1.1.2" so its again a manually thing. And who will it be? The project manager? clearly not. The developer? what if we decided to hold his latest feature and go with other one to the closer version? And finally, me? So it comes back to me as the team leader. But what is my best tool here?

Example, one of my team members finished feature F1, bugs B1 and B2 and he checks them in with their associated PBI.
Other team member finishes features F2 and F3 (very productive of him).
Both of them merge it to the release branch and later i have merged it to production branch.
What is my option at this point to answer the question "What's new in our latest version?" without going to my team members, the TFS history, the TFS current sprint (and maybe older ones)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automate your build and deployment process. As long as developers are associating work items with commits, your releases will automatically be able to display that information and even generate an email.

You didn't specify what version of TFS you're using, but this has been a feature since TFS 2015 Update 2.

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/work-items/email-work-items?view=vsts&tabs=browser#email-release-summary]
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/work-items/email-work-items?view=vsts&tabs=browser#email-release-summary

Comment: I'm using TFS 2018 so this won't a problem. The problem is i can't create this automation in one clear day so doing it one step at a time puts me in a time frame where i need to know what was released while not having automation process. Anyway i accept your answer as clearly its how things should go.